# Show preview on new page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have editor that I can get it's code with js in my page and user can write his html code in it. I want show current user's html code in new window without saving the code in database or something else. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi why dont you store your  values in html5 storage objects such as sessionStorage/localStorage, visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate values temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your values 
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

So you can store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using html5 storage objects

YOu can use the sessionstorage object to store the user's code temporarily for a session and get it on next page using above syntax

Comment: Because of some limitation on use of html5 ( most of my users use old browser and not support html5 ) I can't use this way.

Comment: But this is best way for doing someting like this with new methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps below :

1. On the preview page, place an `IFRAME`.
2. From the first page, where user inputs `HTML`, set a session variable.
3. On click of some button on first page, set the session and redirect to preview page.
4. The preview page is supposed to fetch the session value and display it inside the `IFRAME`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilevuz/1/)**

Comment: Great JS demonstration. Real-time preview. My +1